# I cannot pass my object to another view with NavigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

In my home view, I can see listName and date. Also, I can see productCount when I write elements.productCount, but I cannot see my productCount and listName when I go another view

**HomeView**

```
@StateObject var homeData = HomeViewModel()

// Fetching Data.....
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
@FetchRequest(entity: ShoppingList.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)],animation: .spring()) var results : FetchedResults<ShoppingList>


var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        
        NavigationView{
  
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(list: homeData)){
        
                        ForEach(results){ element in
                            
                   
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        
                                        Text("\(element.listName!)")
                                            .font(.headline)
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .padding(.top, 20)
```

**DetailView**

```
struct DetailView: View {

@ObservedObject var list = HomeViewModel()

var body: some View {
    
    Text("\(list.productCount)")
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You should not create initiate `list` in `DetailView`, because you pass it from home view - only declare it, so like

```
struct DetailView: View {

@ObservedObject var list: HomeViewModel     // << here !!
```

*Btw, it looks strange that you put all `ForEach` into one NavigationLink (is it intended? that might bring you problems later)*

Comment: Where should I put my navigation link? Also, I declared the list as you said but I cannot still show it

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are doing some mistakes in your code (if your case is a `master - detail` app)

- Detail view will contain `Element` object (**item form your fetched list**)

like that :

```
struct DetailView: View {
 var element: Element
 var body: some View {   
    Text("\(element.listName)")
 }
}
```

And your home view :

```
NavigationView{    
 ForEach(results){ element in  
  NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(element: element)){                                           
   VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("\(element.listName!)")
     .font(.headline)
     .foregroundColor(.black)
     .padding(.top, 20)
   }
  }
 }
}
```